# Can you use DAQmx without an NI optical encoder?

Tags: labview, daq-mx

Does DAQmx solely work with NI hardware or can it work with other brands of equipment? If it cannot how would I start to make a block diagram for an optical encoder that stores the position of a stepper motor? Sorry for the newbie question, thank you.

Comment: DAQmx is only for NI hardware. What is the make and model of your optical encoder and how does it interface to the computer?

Comment: I'm working with a Nanotech NOE2 which goes to a BrBoPr++, then goes to a microcomputer (Debian-Linux OS), then USB to the PC.

Comment: If I understand correctly that's an expansion board plugged into a BeagleBone? Then the answer depends entirely on the software that's running on the BeagleBone. Does it appear as a USB serial port when plugged in to the host PC, or a Test and Measurement class device, or something else? In any case you'll need to find out details of the protocol it uses to communicate to the host PC and then use NI-VISA functions in LabVIEW to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

As @AndreTec mentioned, Arduino would be good solution if you have moderate speed motor. You can connect your encoder outputs to two interrupt pins.

However, I encourage you to use pure serial communication between Arduino and LabVIEW to avoid data loss since no LabVIEW addons deals with interrupt up to the best of my knowledge.